# Moving discussion from comments to chat removes deletability ‎- rationale?

Tags: discussion, chat

Prompted by a recent transferral of a long comment discussion to chat by a moderator, I noticed that (this being chat then) previous comments become permanent. Not an issue in this case at all, but sometimes I like to remove a comment for tidying up.

So just out curiosity, are there any serious pros/cons to this state change of user content? Only con that comes to mind right away is the curbed removal of impolite or offensive comments by their authors, but those could be flagged anyway...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I had not considered it.  I have noticed the loss of comment votes but the nature of the Chat makes all comments visible so the value of the votes in the collapsed view is somewhat reduced.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard as pointed out, no gripes, just curiosity (also if this has been discussed already). The post in question sure deserved some de-cluttering.

Answer (score 6):

I think no. On some sites, moderators delete long comment threads or move them to chat more or less arbitrarily simply because there are *too many comments*, which is supposed to be a bad thing. On this site, I trust that our moderators will only move comments to chat if they really represent an ongoing conversation that would be better conducted in the chat room.

The chat has its own nuisances, but so do comments. The only really important disadvantage I can think of would arise if one of the participants in the conversation was a user with not enough points to enter the chat.

Comment: The last disadvantage is not a problem. Chat requires 20 rep, which is under the 50 rep required for commenting everywhere, and [if a user's comments are migrated to chat they can always read and write to that room](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976/184688).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty 50 points are only required for commenting on posts outside of one's own threads; new users can still comment on their own questions and answers to those. I'm happy to learn that the restriction is lifted for the chat when comments are migrated there.